# Danish music similar to singer-songwriter "Coeur de pirate"

Tags: electronic-music

I'm a language enthusiast, and enjoy listening to music in the language that I am learning in so I can hear how words flow together. I can almost speak French as well as English, and I want to move on to Danish. I was wondering if there was any soft listening music artists that I can clearly hear the words in Danish.

Not necessarily genre specific. I'm on a slow phone and don't really have the time to look at all the tags I can use.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia lists a couple of hundred Danish composers featured in Wikipedia articles. Why not go through this list and look for vocal music?

[Danish Composers at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Danish_composers)